# Update multiple record in a row from a single function

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in postgresql and could use a pointer to get forward.

Problem:
I've got a table with several fields. 3 of these needs to be updated with the result from a functions which returns 3 numbers. How do I do that?

Example(which obviously doesn't work):

update gravitational_relations
set x, y, z = SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(a lot of number which comes from a select);

SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY returns 3 numbers.

If only I could save those 3 numbers in each own variable and use them in the
**update ....

set ....**,
 all would be well.

If I should move on to a new design, please tell me and give examples.

Any help is appreciated.

/Michael

Comment: The SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY function returns record or array?

Answer (score 1):

If "a lot of numbers which come from a select" does **not** depend on each record being updated, you may use:

```
UPDATE gravitational_relations
SET (x, y, z) = (f.output_param_name1, f.output_param_name2, f.output_param_name3)
FROM SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(a lot of numbers which come from a select) AS f;
```

Otherwise, if "a lot of numbers which come from a select" depends on each record being updated, you may use something like:

```
UPDATE gravitational_relations
SET (x, y, z) = ((f).output_param_name1, (f).output_param_name2, (f).output_param_name3)
FROM (SELECT id, SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(a lot of numbers which come from a select) AS f FROM gravitational_relations) AS x
WHERE gravitational_relations.id = x.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call your update from within a plpgsql function and call your gravity function from within your update function returning 3 output values. Out1, out2, and out3 for example. Than in your update use those values.

Pseudo code:

```
BEGIN FUNCTION
    EXECUTE SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(out1,out2,out3);

    update gravitational_relations
    set x = out1,
        y = out2,
        z = out3;
END FUNCTION
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html and search for output to see an example of a function that returns output parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't really see how SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY function could return 3 separate numbers, if you're sure that it does, then you can use three variables to read those 3 numbers:

```
SELECT INTO x, y, z SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY();
```

Then you can use those variables to update another table:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1=x, field2=y, field3=z WHERE some_id=some_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the fields directly like so:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    bar1 = (SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(numbers...)).bar1,
       bar2 = (SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY(numbers...)).bar2,
       ...
```

If SQL_CALCULATE_GRAVITY() is stable/immutable, it'll only be called once per row.